# Bootstrap Snippet not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get this snippet I found to work: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-vertical-tab

It works but I can't change the tabs...
Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 bhoechie-tab-container">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 300px; text-align:right;padding-right: 20px;padding-top: 20px">
            <?php
            echo "Logged in as " . $_SESSION['username'];
            ?>
            <br>
            <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 bhoechie-tab-menu">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item active text-center"> <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></h4>
                <br/>
                Test1 </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center"> <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></h4>
                <br/>
                Test2 </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center"> <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></h4>
                <br/>
                Test3 </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center"> <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></h4>
                <br/>
                Test4 </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center"> <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></h4>
                <br/>
                Test5 </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 bhoechie-tab">
            <!-- overview section -->
            <div class="bhoechie-tab-content active">
                <center>
                    Test                        
                </center>
            </div>
            <!-- train section -->
            <div class="bhoechie-tab-content">
                <center>
                </center>
            </div>

            <!-- hotel search -->
            <div class="bhoechie-tab-content">
                <center>
                    <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size:12em;color:#55518a"></h1>
                    <h2 style="margin-top: 0;color:#55518a">Cooming Soon</h2>
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 0;color:#55518a">Hotel Directory</h3>
                </center>
            </div>
            <div class="bhoechie-tab-content">
                <center>
                    <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery" style="font-size:12em;color:#55518a"></h1>
                    <h2 style="margin-top: 0;color:#55518a">Cooming Soon</h2>
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 0;color:#55518a">Restaurant Diirectory</h3>
                </center>
            </div>
            <div class="bhoechie-tab-content">
                <center>
                    <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card" style="font-size:12em;color:#55518a"></h1>
                    <h2 style="margin-top: 0;color:#55518a">Cooming Soon</h2>
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 0;color:#55518a">Credit Card</h3>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #666699;
}

span.glyphicon-link {
    font-size: 5.2em;
}

.btn {border-radius: 0;}
.form-control {border-radius: 0;}
.div {border-radius: 0;}


/*  bhoechie tab */
div.bhoechie-tab-container{
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  opacity: 0.97;
  filter: alpha(opacity=97);
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu{
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a .glyphicon,
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a .fa {
  color: #5A55A3;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a:first-child{
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a:last-child{
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active,
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active .glyphicon,
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active .fa{
  background-color: #666699;
  background-image: #666699;
  color: #ffffff;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active:after{
  content: '';
  margin-top: -13px;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #5A55A3;
}

div.bhoechie-tab-content{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* border: 1px solid #eeeeee; */
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

div.bhoechie-tab div.bhoechie-tab-content:not(.active){
  display: none;
}

.navbar-login
{
    width: 305px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-login-session
{
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.icon-size
{
    font-size: 87px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT (Forgot to add the Javascript code to the post, I use the original one...):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.bhoechie-tab-menu>div.list-group>a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('a.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var index = $(this).index();
    $("div.bhoechie-tab>div.bhoechie-tab-content").removeClass("active");
    $("div.bhoechie-tab>div.bhoechie-tab-content").eq(index).addClass("active");
});
});
```

Comment: Did you also add the Javascript from the Snippet?

Comment: Sorry I forgot! Will update in just a second!

Comment: Just to make it clear. I forgot to ADD it to the POST. I have it in my code...

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using 1.11.0. Also tried with 2.1.1. No difference...

Comment: Works for me with your code: http://www.bootply.com/Qxv4MTPhYs

Comment: There it works but on my server running xampp it doesn't... Is there some kind of a setting or something in xampp or am I missing something else?